# noUiSlider: Adjusting rounded input values

Tags: javascript, jquery, range, rangeslider, nouislider

When I enter a non-rounded number into the #annual-sales input field, the plugin automatically rounds it up or down, depending on "upper" or "lower". 
Is there a way for me to enter a specific number into the field such as 1234567 and have it retain that value? Then sliding to the previous or next value would snap it back into place.

```
<input type="text" id="annual-sales">
<div class="slider-wrap">
  <div class="range-slider-sales-vol"></div>  
</div>

// The first number in the array represents the range. Between the 4 options below I have a range from 1000 - 1000000.
// The second number represents the stepped increments within the given range. From the first to second range the stepped increments are 1000.

var range_all_sliders = {
    'min': [ 1000, 1000 ],
    '33%': [ 100000,  50000 ],
    '66%': [ 500000, 100000 ],
    'max': [ 1000000 ]
};

$('.range-slider-sales-vol').noUiSlider({
    start: [ 1000 ],
    range: range_all_sliders,
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0
    })   
});

// Pips plugin for points along range slider
$('.range-slider-sales-vol').noUiSlider_pips({
    mode: 'positions',
    values: [0,33,66,100],
    density: 4,
    stepped: true
});

// links range slider to input
$('.range-slider-sales-vol').Link("lower").to($('#annual-sales'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by implementing your own `change` handler, overriding the one noUiSlider sets by default.

```
var annualSales = $('#annual-sales'), guard = false;

function setSalesValue(value){
    if ( guard ) return;
    $(this).val(value);
}

annualSales.change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    guard = true;
    slider.val(value);
    guard = false;
});

// links range slider to input
$('.range-slider-sales-vol').Link("lower").to(annualSales, setSalesValue);
```

Notice the use of a `guard` variable: it prevents the slider from updating the input with the value set in the `change` handler.

I've updated your code with a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/a9ng4om2/1/). Try changing the input field; the slider will update, the input value **won't** be reset. Moving the slider **will** update the input.